# Category of concrete categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

Consider the following 2-category:

• It objects are concrete categories, i.e., categories equipped with a faithful functor to $Set$.

• A 1-morphism between $(C_1,U_1)$ and $(C_2,U_2)$ consist of a functor $F:C_1\to C_2$ and a natural transformation $z:U_1\Rightarrow U_2\circ F$.

• Its 2-morphisms are the obvious thing.

**Question:** Is there a name for that notion of functor between concrete categories?

> ... the pair $(F,z)$ is a  *[insert adjective]*  functor from $C_1$ to $C_2$ ...

Comment: What's the obvious thing, if I may ask? [Modifications](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modification)?

Comment: A $2$-morphism from $(F_1,z_1)$ to $(F_2,z_2)$ is a natural transformation $\Phi:F_1\Rightarrow F_2$ wish the property that $z_2=(U_2\circ \Phi)\bullet z_1$, where $\circ$ denotes horizontal composition and $\bullet$ denotes vertical composition.

Comment: This article uses "concrete functor": Porst, _What is concrete equivalence?_
 https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00878502, I think (I can't check right now)

Comment: @David Roberts: Thanks for the pointer. The article you cite assumes that the natural transformation $U_1\Rightarrow U_2\circ F$ is an equivalence (which is something I don't want to assume).

Comment: "(co)lax concrete functor (see [Porst])"?

Comment: There is a good reference about concrete categories: http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf (if you don't know it already).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Concrete functor** is established in the literature for the related notion where the natural transformation is an isomorhpism (see e.g. Porst 1996 [*Concrete Categories Are Concretely Equivalent if…*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00124121.pdf)) — i.e. the sub-2-category of the slice 2-category of **CAT** over **Set** on faithful functors.

Your 2-category is similarly the sub-2-category on faithful functors of the [*colax* slice 2-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/slice+2-category) of **CAT** over **Set**.  So it seems very natural to call your notion **colax concrete functors**, though as far as I can find this term hasn’t been used before.  A *lax concrete functor* would be the same thing but with the transformation in the other direction.